# Polygon decomposition into simple polygons

Tags: polygon

I am looking for solutions for dividing a complex non-self intersecting 2d polygon into simple polygons (triangles, rectangles, parts of a circle). This is so I can assemble human readable proof of the total area of the polygon. This kind of excercise is required by German DIN standard for writing formal simplified proofs of the area of rooms. The only example I am able to find is part of the Allplan and Revit Areabook plugin, showing example outputs.[image] [image]

Any suggestions are welcome.